# change drive letters in triple boot

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, operating-systems

i currently triple boot vista (c drive), xp (e drive) and linux (drive doesnt show up in windows)
My data is on d drive.
I want to get rid of vista installation and move xp to c drive (make default OS) and then i will install W7 RC on the e drive later.
Is there a way i can change the drive letters so i dont have to reinstall xp? 
Im scared I wont be able to boot windows properly if i delete the C drive.

Comment: If you launch "Disk Management Console", which drive is listed as being the "System" drive?  That's the one that would hold the Windows Boot Manager and be required to boot any Windows OS currently installed on the system.

Comment: yeh the c drive is the system drive..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had XP on the C:\ drive and installed Vista on D:. When I booted into Vista, it appeared it was on C:\, when I booted into XP, it also showed as C:. Vista functions differently from XP; when you start it, it shows it's on the C:\ drive. So all these letters don't really mean anything in the end.

Just try and install Windows 7 directly, without making all these changes. Just pop in the Windows 7 DVD, format the Vista partition from the installer and continue installing 7. When done, the Windows 7 bootloader will probably figure out what to do with XP.

Comment: yeh not a bad idea. thanks
not a perfect solution though because ive heard that some programs dont play nice if they are not installed on the c drive (i will be using xp as my main system). 
cheers

Comment: I think you can play around wiht the drive letters. I know Paragon Partition Manager can change drive letters for you without needing to do anything else. Give that a try and see what happens. They have a trial version on their site: http://www.partition-manager.com/

Comment: i did what u said and it works well thanks
now i just have to figure out how to add linux to the boot list!
(ill try easy bcd)

Comment: It should be fairly easy with EasyBCD; I've actually done that a while back, although I can't really remember the way to do it. BTW, if you found my answer helpful, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually Windows XP is very picky about being located on the C: drive especially if you have a prior install and have programs all up and running it gets messy; best I would say is to get a third party Drive managing software and do some adjusting; I use Acronis software ie Disk director no plug intended I've had it for over a year and it works very well.

Most important thing however is Backup, Backup, Backup acronis could help you there also or any other software; then open your disk software you can select change drive E: to C: and so on I can only speak for Acronis as that's all I use it will ask for a restart do all the drives in one simple pre boot screen and vala!

Good luck